# Disabling button after click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Private Function StoreCouponCode() As String
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim sql As New SqlCommand("", con)
        Dim sqlGetSlNo As New SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(SlNo) FROM Coupons WHERE CustID=" & Convert.ToInt16(HFCustID.Value) & " AND BusiID=" & Convert.ToInt16(HFBusiID.Value) & " AND OfferID=" & Convert.ToInt16(HFOfferID.Value), con)
        Dim sNo, UserID, couponCode, offerCheck As String
        Dim slNo As Int16

        Try
            UserID = getCurrentUserID()
            con.Open()
            sNo = Convert.ToString(sqlGetSlNo.ExecuteScalar)     'fteches latest serial no for the coupon
            If sNo = "" Then
                slNo = 0
            Else
                slNo = Convert.ToInt16(sNo) + 1
            End If
            couponCode = MakeCouponCode(slNo)
            offerCheck = couponCode.Substring(13, 3)
            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Coupons VALUES (" & _
                                  HFCustID.Value & "," & HFBusiID.Value & "," & HFOfferID.Value & ",'" & _
                                  Today.Date & "'," & Convert.ToString(slNo) & "," & offerCheck & ",'" & couponCode & "','" & _
                                  UserID & "'," & LblPayInAdv.Text & "," & LblPayLater.Text & ",'" & Convert.ToString(Date.Now) & "')"
            sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            couponCode = "N/A"
        Finally
            con.Dispose()
            sql.Dispose()
        End Try
        Return couponCode
    End Function





Protected Sub CmdGetCoupon_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles CmdGetCoupon.Click
        If User.Identity.Name = "" Then
            LblMessage.Text = "You need to login first!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim couponCode As String = StoreCouponCode()
        Response.Redirect("~/Coupon.aspx?CouponCode=" & couponCode, True)
    End Sub
```

When the user clicks on the `CmdGetCoupon` it takes some time to redirect..so the user clicks on the `CmdGetCoupon` more than once,which results in multiple coupon generation from a single user account.

I want to display a message "Please Wait While Your Coupon Is Being Generated" and disable the `CmdGetCoupon` so that the user  cannot click multiple times....Any Ideas??How to do this??

Answer (score 5):

Do this in javascript - use the `OnClientClick` to call a function that disables the passed in form element.

```
// On button
... OnClientClick="DisableMe(this);" ...

// Javascript
function DisableMe(elem)
{
   elem.disabled = true;
   // more code to show message
}
```

Comment: I want the page to redirect and restrict the user from clicking the button twice or more.

Comment: @SifyJuhy - If the button is a server side button, it should still submit, but not twice.

Comment: It is a server side `ImageButton`...but using your code dosent execute the Button Click function..I mean the page does not redirect.

Answer (score 2):

In your html side you have to add it in the onClientClick property:

```
<asp:Button ID="CmdGetCoupon" runat="server" onClientClick="this.disabled=true;" />
```

**Edit:**
Since @Oded so accurately pointed out that my first answer does not address the display of a message, here are a couple of options.

```
<span id="PleaseWaitContainer"></span>
<asp:Button ID="CmdGetCoupon" runat="server" onClientClick="this.disabled=true;document.getElementById('PleaseWaitContainer').innerText='Please Wait While Your Coupon Is Being Generated';" />
```

Or

```
<asp:Button ID="CmdGetCoupon" runat="server" onClientClick="this.disabled=true;alert('Please wait while your coupon is being generated...';" />
```

Comment: Concise, be this will not display a message to the user, as the OP requested.

Comment: @Oded: I see you went the extra mile by adding `// more code to show message'. I postulate that your answer also does not fulfill OP's request.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button in the click handler, because you're going to redirect to another page, so don't care about any other logic.
Otherwise, if you're performing any async operation, again, disable it as soon as you click it, and in the async callback handler depending on the logic either enable it back or handle it properly in other way.